# Views Page not showing pager

Tags: 7, views, paging

I've got a Views Page showing Article teasers. There are lots of Articles in the db and I'm only showing 5 per page in the View, but the Pager is not showing up at all. Here is my Views configuration, am I doing something wrong? Is there a bug?

[image]

The preview in the Views screen does not show a Pager at the bottom of the content teaser and it also doesn't show on the real page.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you add, on the header of the view, the results summary for the view? And what happens if you change the content from teaser to fields?

Comment: Under "Advanced -> Theme" are any of the templates overridden? Or does /most-recent have a template applied?

Comment: Just to be clear - are you sure that you have more than 5 articles that are published?

Comment: When I add a Results Summary in the Header it shows "Display 1 -5 of 14" so I definitely have more content.

Comment: Advanced -> Theme doesn't show any overridden templates and that's what I expected to see.

Comment: If I switch over to use Fields instead of Teasers, the pager DOES show up (wth?) but, of course, I've lost all of the styling that came with my theme on the teasers. I'd really prefer not to have to restyle EVERYTHING just because of what appears to be a bug. Any help?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This can have a whole bunch of reasons. I'm just providing the imho most probable non-obvious one:

Go to "pager settings" (on your screenshot click "Paged, 5 items") and change the "pager id". Docs say this is only needed when there is more than one view on a page, but i saw live examples where this fixed a non-showing pager on a single-view page.

Comment: I have long since fixed whatever page I was working on for them, but I believe this comment strikes at the heart of the problem I had (even though I solved it differently), so I'll accept it.

Comment: @KennyWyland could you please provide ur soln. too. Thanks.

Comment: This was the right answer for me!  I had recently included another view on the page, and apparently there was a pager id conflict.

Answer (score 11):

I came across this issue recently since upgrading to views 3.8. for me the issue was caused by views_php module as discussed here: https://www.drupal.org/node/2276165 there is also a patch available to fix it.

Comment: Thanks Lee. I applied the patch from the link and it worked. This is a second correct solution when using views 3.8 and a views_php field within your view.

Comment: Worked for me with views_php 7.x-1.0-alpha1 as well.

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/views_php-pager_missing-2276165-1.patch - Patch worked for me as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The solution described in the answer from aexl worked for me.

For those who don't understand that answer, maybe this refined version of it helps:

> Go to "pager settings" (on your screenshot click "Paged, 5 items") and
>   change the "pager id" **to something like 5 or any number instead of
>   leaving empty**.